# Cannot start Rails server- DEPRECATION ERROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm attempting to start my rails server using Cloud9 and am receiving the following message:

> DEPRECATION WARNING: The configuration option `config.serve_static_assets` has been renamed to `config.serve_static_files` to clarify its role (it merely enables serving everything in the `public` folder and is unrelated to the asset pipeline). The `serve_static_assets` alias will be removed in Rails 5.0. Please migrate your configuration files accordingly. (called from  at /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/application.rb:25)
>   => Booting WEBrick
>   => Rails 4.2.5 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:8080
>   => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
>   => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>   Exiting
>   /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:177:in `rescue in spec': Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add`gem 'pg'`to your Gemfile (and ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord). (Gem::LoadError)
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:174:in`spec'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:50:in `establish_connection'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:120:in`block (2 levels) in '
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in`execute_hook'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:45:in `block in run_load_hooks'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in`each'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:44:in `run_load_hooks'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:315:in`'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activerecord-4.2.5/lib/active_record/base.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in`require'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:238:in`block in load_dependency'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:238:in`load_dependency'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
>           from /home/ubuntu/workspace/app/models/podcast.rb:1:in`'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in `load'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:457:in`block in load_file'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:647:in `new_constants_in'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:456:in`load_file'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:354:in `require_or_load'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:494:in`load_missing_constant'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:184:in `const_missing'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in`const_get'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `block in constantize'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in`each'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `inject'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in`constantize'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:566:in `get'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:597:in`constantize'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise.rb:315:in `get'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:83:in`to'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:78:in `modules'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:95:in`routes'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:162:in `default_used_route'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise/mapping.rb:72:in`initialize'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise.rb:345:in `new'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise.rb:345:in`add_mapping'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:243:in `block in devise_for'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:242:in`each'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/devise-4.4.1/lib/devise/rails/routes.rb:242:in `devise_for'
>           from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/routes.rb:7:in`block in '
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:434:in `instance_exec'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:434:in`eval_block'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/actionpack-4.2.5/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:412:in `draw'
>           from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/routes.rb:1:in`'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in`block in load'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in`load'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in`each'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in`reload!'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in`execute'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:27:in `updater'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in`execute_if_updated'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:69:in `block in <module:Finisher>'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in`instance_exec'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in`block in run_initializers'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:228:in `block in tsort_each'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:350:in`block (2 levels) in each_strongly_connected_component'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:431:in `each_strongly_connected_component_from'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:349:in`block in each_strongly_connected_component'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in`call'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:347:in `each_strongly_connected_component'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:226:in`tsort_each'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.4/lib/ruby/2.3.0/tsort.rb:205:in `tsort_each'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in`run_initializers'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/application.rb:352:in `initialize!'
>           from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config/environment.rb:5:in`'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in`block in require'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/activesupport-4.2.5/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in`require'
>           from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:3:in `block in <main>'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-1.6.9/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in`instance_eval'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-1.6.9/lib/rack/builder.rb:55:in `initialize'
>           from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:in`new'
>           from /home/ubuntu/workspace/config.ru:in `<main>'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-1.6.9/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in`eval'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-1.6.9/lib/rack/builder.rb:49:in `new_from_string'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-1.6.9/lib/rack/builder.rb:40:in`parse_file'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-1.6.9/lib/rack/server.rb:300:in `build_app_and_options_from_config'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-1.6.9/lib/rack/server.rb:209:in`app'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:61:in `app'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/rack-1.6.9/lib/rack/server.rb:337:in`wrapped_app'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:139:in `log_to_stdout'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:78:in`start'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in`tap'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in`run_command!'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/railties-4.2.5/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
>           from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/rails:9:in`require'
>           from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/rails:9:in `<top (required)>'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in`load'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/rails.rb:28:in `call'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client/command.rb:7:in`call'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/client.rb:30:in `run'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/bin/spring:49:in`'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in `load'
>           from /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.4/gems/spring-2.0.2/lib/spring/binstub.rb:31:in`'
>           from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/spring:15:in `require'
>           from /home/ubuntu/workspace/bin/spring:15:in`'
>           from bin/rails:3:in `load'
>           from bin/rails:3:in`'

Process exited with code: 1

Any idea on how to fix the problem? I ran Bundle Update multiple times with no luck.

Comment: Do you have `gem 'pg'` in your Gemfile?

Comment: I do. It didn't make a difference.

Comment: There seems to be an issue with [rails and pg 1.0.0](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/31673).

Comment: Since `bundle update` upgrades gems to their latest versions, use `bundle install` instead. Try setting your pg gem to `gem 'pg', '~> 0.21'`, do a bundle install, and see if error gets fixed.

Comment: I had problems with version 0.21 try adding `gem 'pg', '0.20.0'` to your Gemfile and run `bundle install`

Answer (score 0):

Try to the following, edit your Gemfile like below

```
gem 'pg', '~> 0.20.0'
```

Or

```
gem 'pg', '~> 0.11'
```

Then bundle install and try, it's working on my hand.

Hope it helps